# jQuery DataTables post data to server

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app and I'm using jQuery DataTables as grid.
I need to manage grids' data on client side and then post it to the server and process it then.
What's the easiest way of doing this? How to post json from DataTables along with other form data? And is there any way to map JSON from DataTables to C# objects?
Thank you!

Comment: here is a link with webforms. a complete video series. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kHOoD7As2o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guide on how to integrate jQuery datatables with MVC:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

Comment: This is trivial but I need to post the data from grid to server.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the generalized response... code samples and research are probably best deferred in this case:

I would personally be tempted to use DataTables' `fnGetData` function to grab the table as an array. At that point you can use an appropriate tool to convert it to whatever format you need, and post it to your server-side.

There is at least one well known JSON utility (json.js I think it's called...?) that can convert to JSON, at which point you would probably need to stringify it. Then you would post it, and then if ASP.NET already has a utility, convert over to a C## object.

Only at the end do I think to ask this: why is there a need to POST the whole table? You might be better off only POSTing cells with values that you've updated, etc.

Comment: Um, I general It's okay. But I want to see real examples of doing this with as less as possible elbow grease.

Answer (score 0):

I've made an alternative to DataTables where it's easy to post additional data since my plugin uses a form while fetching data.

https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table/wiki/Basic-usage

It also got an MVC3 integration package:

https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table/wiki/Asp.net-mvc3-introduction